# Populate layout with HorizontalListView

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I have used [DevsmartLib-Android](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android)
 to create HorizontalListView

Below is the layout for the HorizontalListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
tools:context="com.test.demo.HorizontalListViewActivity">

    <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ddd"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the implementation in the adapter. I am unable to figure out how to inflate this `HorizontalListView` multiple times to get the desired result

```
 private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {

    private View.OnClickListener mOnButtonClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(HorizontalListViewActivity.this, "Item Clicked"+v, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vv = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) vv.findViewById(R.id.title);
        Button button = (Button) vv.findViewById(R.id.clickbutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(mOnButtonClicked);
        title.setText(dataObjects[position]);

        return vv;
    }
```

This is how the app looks now. I am trying to inflate the `HorizontalListView` inside a `listview`. How do I take this further from here?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand 'how to inflate this HorizontalListView multiple times to get the desired result', but Maybe you want put many HorizontalListView in One Layout.

If my understanding is correct, here is your answer.

Using [ScrollView](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) to inflate layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#fff">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout  
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
                android:id="@+id/listview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ddd"
            />

            <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
                android:id="@+id/listview2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ddd"
            />

            <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
                android:id="@+id/listview3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ddd"
            />

            <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
                android:id="@+id/listview4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ddd"
            />

            <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
                android:id="@+id/listview5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ddd"
            />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```